# archiving strategies and limitations of data in a table

Tags: sql, database, hibernate, database-design, jpa

Environment: Jboss, Mysql, JPA, Hibernate

Our web application will be catering to a large amount of users (~ 1,000,000) and there are a lots of child table where user specific data are stored (e.g. personal, health, forum contributions ...).

1. What would be the best practice to archive user & user specific information. 
   [a] Would it be wise to move the archived user & user specific information to their respective tables within the same database (e.g. user_archive, user_forum_comments_archive ...) OR
   [b] Would you just mark the database entries with a flag in the original table(s) and just query only non archived entries.
2. We have a unique constraint on User.loginid, how do you handle this requirement if the users are archived via 1-[a] (i.e if a user with loginid 'samuel' gets moved into the archive table and if a new user gets added with the same name in the original table, how would you prevent this. What would be the best strategy to address the unique key constraints.
3. We have a requirement to selectively archive records and bring it back if necessary, will you rely on database tools are would you handle this via your persistence APIs exposed by the JPA entity model.

Comment: First of all, what operations do you expect to be able to perform on archived data? Apart from point 2 and 3, let's say for example that I create a few entries in a forum, and later I stop contributing and get "archived". Are my contributions still visible among the ones made by active users, or do they get archived too? If yes, what data can someone access through the forum (i.e. is my public profile still visible)? What kind of policies do you have for people "going active again"? What percentage of active vs. inactive users do you expect?

Comment: I guess forum contributions should be visible since the forum still has many posts (since archival of forum comments specific to a user, might render the conversation completely useless). The user's public profile need not be shown to other users post archival. I would probably want to archive user those users who are not active in the system (~ 10% of the total users in the system). Again, I am just looking for ideas on what would be the correct approach to this problem and my intention is to keep the table size as small as possible so that queries are faster for the active users.

Comment: if you plan on having 1,000,000 users I sure hope you use auto generate/identity numeric PK for them and not user names like 'samuel'.  You crush your index performance dragging that string everywhere.

Comment: Yes, I have an auto generated unique id and User.loginid is supposed to be unique in the system.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Personally, I'd go for solution "[a]".

Having things split on two table sets (current and archived) would make things a bit hard to manage in terms of common RDBMS concepts (example: forum comment author would be a foreign key pointing to the user's table... but you can't have a field behave as a foreign key to two different tables).

You could go for a compromise (users table uses solution "a", all the other tables like profile get archived to a twin table like per solution "b") but this would make things unnecessarily complicated for your code (in some cases you have to look at the non-archived, in some to the archived only, in some other cases to the union of both).

Solution A would easily solve #2 and #3 requirements, too. Uniqueness of user name is easy to enforce if everything is in the same table, and resurrecting archived users is just a matter of flipping a bit (Archived=Y/N) on the main user table.

10% is not much, I doubt that the difference in terms of performance would really justify the extra complexity (and risk of bugs).

Comment: are you suggesting that you would use 1-[b] instead of 1-[a] to avoid the complications?

Comment: Yes. Put an index on the Archived flag so that the SQL optimizer can quickly trim out the archived users (when you don' t need them) and you should be doing ok.

Answer (score 2):

I would put an archived flag on the table and then create a view to use when you don't want to see archived records. That way people will be more consistent in applying the archive flag I suspect.